# JAVA Android dowload XML resource file with strings

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm developping an Android APP, and my questions is this:

The app is done and working, i have every string in the XML file and different languages, my problem is, the app can do a lot off different thing, imagine this, the app can be used by a farmer who need to retrieve info about some cows, but then, it can be used by a car shop, where he collects data from his storage facilty, so, the app has to make some changes, specially in the strings, it's quite awkward to have "Insert COW ID" on a byer form for example....

I just need some ideias and to know if it's possible and how

Thanks

**EDIT:**

why the hell is this downvoted??? seriously... just because i don't ask specifics is trash?? off-topic?? i've seen wuestions worse and nobody cars and still online.

thanks to the guys who bothered to answear...

Comment: are you talking about with labeling the same app?

Comment: no, i have a form, with labels and inputs, what i need is to change the labels, when the users logs in, it dowloads the database parameters, and those strings are used for that, the problem is, some labels ar "hardcoded" in the string resource XML, i need to "change" that XML file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant store dynamic values in XML file. values in strings.xml are static you cant change it in runtime. in your case labels are dynamic so dont use Strings.xml if you want to store dynamic values instead try using sqllite database that checks for name-value pair(check parameter and set label) 
for more storage options see [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: that is what i'm doing right now :) the problem is the database it's getting huge and quite confusing, it would be better to yust use different XML resource, but thanks ;)